# Can't load any PHP file or see any error in the logs using nginx and php7

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, server

I've just recently installed Nginx 1.8 and PHP7 on my server trying to make it serve my application.

When I make my webroot folder index file an HTML file which just returns `Hey`, then I can see the page loaded with that text.

However, when I try to replace that `index.html` file with `index.php` file I just see a blank page and no errors being spat.

I tried to look into `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` as-well as my site error log: `/var/log/nginx/my-website-error.log`. Couldn't find any error there.

I tried to maybe look at the PHP7.0-FPM error log found at `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log` but nothing there as-well.

I made sure to edit my `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` file and set `display_erorrs = On` and `error_reporting=E_ALL`.

I still can't see any error and I can't execute any PHP code.

My Nginx config file which passes the php execution to FPM looks like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: what is the content of index.php?

Comment: @MaxP. Hey. I've tried several things. I tried the `phpinfo()` one and then just a plain `echo "hey";`. I've also tried using the framework Laravel and I get the same blank page. It is as if .php files are simply being ignored or not passed correctly to FPM.

Comment: try to add `fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Comment: @MaxP. I will be home in an hour and will be able to test it. However, where should I put it? Before including the params file? Also, what makes you think it will solve the problem? I don't even know what FPM is doing with that param

Comment: Yes, before including the params file.  This parameter defines the script that php should execute. Also I compared your config with mine (php5) and found this difference.

Comment: @MaxP. I will try it and let you know. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @MaxP. It worked! thanks!

Comment: @MaxP. Hey. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it and for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` before including the params file. This parameter defines the script that php should execute.